# I am getting a error like this: "ERROR TypeError: res.Data.map is not a function" in Ionic4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

This is my code: home.page.ts

```
 coinDetails(coin, index){
      if(this.detailToggle[index])
      this.detailToggle[index] = false;
      else {
        this.detailToggle.fill(false);

        this._data.getCoin(coin)
        .subscribe(res => {
          this.details = res['DISPLAY'][coin]['USD'];

          this.detailToggle[index]= true;

          this._data.getChart(coin)
          .subscribe(res => {

           let coinHistory = res['Data'].map((a) => (a.close));

            setTimeout(() => {
              this.chart[index] = new Chart ('canvas' + index, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                  labels: coinHistory,
                  datasets: [{
                    data: coinHistory,
                    borderColor: '#3cba9f',
                    fill: false
                  }
                ]
              },
                  options: {
                    tooltips: {
                      callbacks: {
                        label: function(tooltipItems,data) {
                          return "$" + tooltipItems.yLabel.toString();
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    reponsive: true,
                    legend: {
                      display: false
                    },
                    scales: {
                      xAxes: [{
                        display: false
                      }],
                      yAxes: [{
                        display: false
                      }],
                    }
                  }
              });
            }, 250);

          });

        });

      }
    }
    }
```

data.service.ts

```
  getChart(coin){
    return this._http.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/histoday?fsym="+coin+"&tsym=USD&limit=30&aggregate=1&e=CCCAGG")
    .pipe(map(result => this.result = result));
  }
```

I just want to show the line chart on my application, and I stock on this process it keeps showing the ERROR TypeError: res.Data.map is not a function when I am trying to show the line chart.

I am hopinng someone can help me. Thankyou guys!

I am just a newbie in ionic guys, I will really appreciate if someone is going to help me

Comment: This means that `res['Data']` isn't an array. Have you tried logging that value to the console to see what it is? Also, it's better to use a `tap` instead of a `map` if you want to perform an action such as `this.result = result`. This indicates that you want to perform an action as a side-effect without returning a different value.

Comment: Another FYI - it's better to use `switchMap` instead of creating a nested subscription. This isn't the cause of your problem, just a heads up.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the `Data` property on the object returned from `this._data.getChart` is defined, but isn't an array. You should try logging the `res` to see what types the properties are.

I recommend refactoring your function. The 2 subscriptions can be run in parallel using a `forkJoin`, as they aren't dependent on each other.

```
coinDetails(coin, index) {
  if (this.detailToggle[index]) {
    this.detailToggle[index] = false;
    return;
  }

  this.detailToggle.fill(false);

  // forkJoin to run 2 subscriptions in parallel
  forkJoin([
    this._data.getCoin(coin).pipe(
      // let the individual calls update the state they are responsible for maintaining
      tap(res => {
        this.details = res['DISPLAY'][coin]['USD'];
        this.detailToggle[index]= true;
      })
    ),
    this._data.getChart(coin).pipe(
      tap(res => {
        // log the result here to see what the data type is
        console.log(res);
        // ***** ERROR OCCURS HERE *****
        this.coinHistory = res['Data'].map(a => a.close);
      })
    )
  ]).subscribe(() => {
    // not sure why this is in a timeout, but have left it that way
    setTimeout(() => {
      // move update chart functionality into separate function for readability
      // new function not shown as it is irrelevant to the problem
      this.updateChart(index)
    }, 250);
  });
}
```